# I can't make an input be required with Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I'm starting with Angular and I'm on a project where I have to validate the inputs so they can't be left clear, every input must me completed.

It's an html and we have a .ts file.

This is an extract of the html:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input  type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="factory"
            [(ngModel)]="factory.company">
</div>
```

I need to validate this factory input but when I was watching tutorials all I needed to do was to write 'required' inside the `<input>` and that was it but I had a `<form>` and every input was inside this form, and this html doesn't have a `<form>` and when I put one the design was horrible and I couldn't work.

Comment: The required attribute is only enforced on form submission which means that it can only be used on elements inside a form. If you can't use a form you will have to figure out another way to do validation.

Comment: @Lex thanks for answering. Do you have any idea how to do it? It's my first time in Angular, I had always used <form> in the few html pages I've worked on and I don't get it wh there's no form. And in every example I've done I have to put the script with the Angular url and my javascript file, here there's nothing linked between the html and the TypeScript file

Comment: `when I put one the design was horrible and I couldn't work` <= what do you mean by this? Adding a form should not do anything odd to the design.

Comment: @elkaco How you validate will depend on your specific situation, but simply checking for a value in the various properties inside whatever method is handling the submit would be an obvious place to start.

Comment: @Igor is right - a form is a non-visible element so unless you have specific CSS selectors or you mismatched the opening and closing of the form tag it should not affect the layout of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using required fields (in login page) :

```
<form [formGroup]='loginForm' (submit)="login(loginForm.value)">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="login-mail">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required="">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="login-mail">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" pattern=".{8,20}" required="">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 login-do">
                <label class="hvr-shutter-in-horizontal login-sub">
                    <input type="submit" value="login" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </form>
```

in the `login.component.ts` , u should make some changes:

1) import some modules :

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators}  from '@angular/forms';
```

2) in oninit function :

```
loginForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb : FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit(){
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email : ["", Validators.required],
      password : ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Hope that helps u :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you should be able to add a form element. However, if you cannot as you have said then you can add the ngForm directive onto any element to achieve the same behavior as having the form element.

See this plunker for examples using ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/94z2Eld3EkWoPD83kFNV?p=preview)

```
//our root app component
import {Component, OnInit, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Model Driven Form</label>
          <input  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="companyModel"
                  [formControl]="companyModel">
          <span [hidden]="companyModel.valid || companyModel.pristine">REQUIRED!</span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" ngForm #myForm="ngForm">
          <label>Template Driven Form</label>
          <input  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  name="companyTemplate"
                  ngModel
                  id="companyTemplate"
                  #companyTemplate="ngModel"
                  required>
          <span [hidden]="companyTemplate.valid || companyTemplate.pristine">REQUIRED!</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  companyModel: FormControl
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Form Validation Demo'
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyModel = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```